# Sharepoint on HyperV

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are looking to migrate our Sharepoint App server to a Hyper-V VM and the Sql Server holding the Sharepoint databases in another Hyper-V VM on the same physical box. Sharepoint here is not heavily used. 
We were thinking of creating one large Raid10 array for all the disks but were not sure about how to configure the virtual disks. Should the database datafiles be on their own virtual disk and the log and tempDB be on their own?
Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a single underlying LUN, it largely doesn't matter how you arrange the files within vDisks, though I still separate MDF/LDF/TempDb files myself even in such a similar environment.

Answer (score 0):

As Trevor already mentioned.. It doesn‘t really matter in a virtualized Environment if you Place all of the vDisks on the same LUN.

To keep Migration as simple as possible, i Recommeed you to keep the existing Disk Layout from your physical Environment. Place every Disk on a separate VHDX file. Do Not use Partitions within one VHDX. This Setup will make it easy for you to expand every Disk later if needed.